# Excel VBA with 3 nested loops

Tags: excel, vba

I want to give Multiple Checkboxes within my userform a caption coming from a cell. Since I don't want to write down every single reference, I would like to use a loop. Unfortunately, I have no clue how to do that.

I have 8 checkboxes per Workday and 23 Workdays in total. The naming is like whis WD1_1, WD1_2 ... WD1_8, WD2_1, WD2_2 ... WD2_8.

WD1_1 get's the value from the tab "tasks" cell B2. From there on, it is always +1.

The issue I have is, that I can't just loop until 185, since three things are changing: Count up the task number and the cell number, when task 8 in WD1 is reached count up WD +1 and restart task number from 1 to 8 and also keep counting up the cell reference.

I just get that going for one instance, for example the cell reference, but not all three together.

This is what I have to loop through the Tasks per WD, but I can't figure out how to count up the Workdays and also the cell number:

```
 For x = 1 To 23
 For i = 1 To 8
 For y = 2 To 185
        
      If Controls("WD" & x & "_" & i).Caption = "" Then
        Controls("WD" & x & "_" & i).Visible = False
        Else
        Controls("WD" & x & "_" & i).Visible = True
      End If
    
      If Sheets("Tasks").Range("I" & y) = 1 Then
        Controls("WD" & x & "_" & i).Value = True
        Else
        Controls("WD" & x & "_" & i).Value = False
      End If

 Next y, i, x
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I am a step further, I can also loop through WD and Task # at the same time, but for some reason, looping through the cells doesn't work. My formula only tasks the last number for the cell reference for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. My error was to go through a third loop. Deleting the third loop and then use a linear function to go through each line is the right way to do it:

```html
 Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer

 For x = 1 To 23
 For i = 1 To 8

      If Controls("WD" & x & "_" & i).Caption = "" Then
        Controls("WD" & x & "_" & i).Visible = False
        Else
        Controls("WD" & x & "_" & i).Visible = True
    End If

    If Sheets("Tasks").Range("I" & (x - 1) * 8 + i + 1).Value = 1 Then
       Controls("WD" & x & "_" & i).Value = True
    Else
      Controls("WD" & x & "_" & i).Value = False
    End If

 Next i, x
```